# The right place for the Js to render a partial in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render, renderpartial

My plan was to update a partial via a klick-event where I fetch some data via ajax.
So i opened my assets/javascripts directory and put the code in the js file of the module I planed to call it on. I managed to fetch the data and to call some "html() or text()" on the div. But as soon as I tried to call

```
.html("<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => 'job') ) %>")
```

my controller told me unknown method "render". So I red in many other Threats that the assets directory was not build for static content. 
But now comes the question where to put it if not in assets?
I tried to put it in the view/model folder (with the same name as the aktion 'show'). But it wouldn't load. Yes I told the Controller in the show action to respond_to format.js.

So where should I put the js-File and how to call it? Or is there even a method to let it in the assets-directory and beeing able to call render?

---

Thanks for your answer! Sadly I do exactly that but I doesnt work. So here is my Code:

/app/views/events/show.js.erb.coffee:

```
$(document).ready ->
  url = window.location
  url = String(url).split('/')
  event_id = url[$.inArray( "events" , url) + 1]
  $('.position').click ->
    position_id = $(this).attr("id")
    $.ajax '/events/'+event_id+'/eventpositions/'+position_id+'/eventjobs'
      dataType: 'json'
      success: (result)->
        $( '#'+position_id ).find('.jobs').html("<%= escape_javascript( render( :partial => 'job') ) %>")
        alert result[1].job_id
```

/app/views/events/show.html.haml:

```
%p#notice{:xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/html"}= notice
%p
  %b Name:
  = @event.name
  \ 
  %b Plz:
  = @event.plz
%p
  %b Personal:
  - @eventpositions.each do |p|
    .position{:id => "#{p.id}"}
    %b
      Position: #{Position.find(p.position_id).name} Anzahl: #{p.quantity} Aufträge: #{p.eventjobs.all.count}
    .jobs

  = link_to 'Neuer Auftrag', new_event_eventposition_eventjob_path(@event.id,p.id)
  %br
  %br
= link_to 'Neue Position', new_event_eventposition_path(@event.id)
= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event)
|
\#{link_to 'Back', events_path}
```

/app/views/events/_job.html.haml:

```
.jobs
  - eventjobs.each do |j|
    User: #{User.find(Job.find(j.job_id).user_id).email}
    %br
```

/app/controllers/events_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @agency = Agency.find(current_agent.agency_id)
  @event = @agency.events.find(params[:id])
  @eventpositions = @event.eventpositions.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @event }
    format.js
  end
end
```

So the Code does work without Javascript. All renders and is fine. But my main Problem now is that it wont even react to a click event if I place it in the app/views/events Folder. As soon as I place it in the assets directory I works like a charm, but wont render.
So what am I missing? Why does my js Code does not get loaded?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally for this kind of thing, I'll name it the same as a particular action, such as `show.js.erb`, and then use the format.js as you have in the controller. If you're using coffeescript, it will need to be named `show.js.coffee.erb`. If this does not work, can you post the code of your view where this onclick event is setup?

**Edit for using the show javascript code**

Because you're using the show action, should just be able to do this:

```
= link_to "Show", @event, :remote => true, :format => :js
```

Adjust the event variable there as you need to, but it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Sadly I do exactly that and it doesn't work, most probably I miss something.

Comment: Still doesnt fix it for me. Even if I change it to a plan .js File (or a js.erb) it doesnt load or do anything with it. Even when I try to execute smth like: $('.position').click(function() {
  return alert ( 'Testing' );
 });What could tell RoR not to load it?

Comment: Had a better look at your code, where are you trying to load this js file? You mentioned a click event, can you post the code that contains this click event? Thanks.

Comment: I try to load it with this one /app/views/events/show.js.erb.coffee (see Code below) but even if I Just make the click event as posted before nothing happens at all. So I guess the loading part is the Problem! Where do I tell Rails to include this js on this side?